# UK passport expiration

Tags: passports

I have a UK passport and live in the US with a US green card. My passport expires on May 30th. I'm planning to travel outside the US and be back on April 22nd.

Is it possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because questions about long-term immigration live on [expatriates.se]. Although you're asking about a short-term trip outside the US, the core of your question is about your long-term stay in the US on your green card.

Comment: I would disagree that it's off topic. The question is "can I travel", i.e. do short term travel.

Comment: Actually the question is more about "can I come back to the US with an expired passport as a PR?" Which belongs definitely to Expats.

Comment: Your problem is not with the USA, but with the countries you wish to visit. Many (if not most) want six months validity from date of entry.

Comment: How soon do you plan to start traveling? The last time I renewed my UK passport, while living in the US, it took about a week total elapsed time.

Comment: @dda unless I am misreading, April is prior to May, so the passport won't be expired on return - just less than the 6 months validity most expect you to have left.

Answer (score 5):

It is not clear whether you are asking about your ability to enter the foreign country you will be visiting, or your ability to enter the US.

For entry to the foreign country you will be visiting, that depends on the rules of that country, which you have not mentioned. Some countries may have requirements for a certain number of months of passport validity to visit.

For entry to the US, there is no length of passport validity required for an entering immigrant (there is a 6-month requirement for nonimmigrants with certain passports (not including the UK), but this doesn't apply to immigrants); and, furthermore, returning US permanent residents with a valid green card are [not even required](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1191/~/traveling-outside-of-the-u.s.---documents-needed-for-lawful-permanent-residents) to have a passport at all to enter the US.